# to_capabilities() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get('http://amazon.de')
print(driver.title)
```

I get the error

> to_capabilities() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: isn't it  `options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Options() from

```py
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
```

and not from

```py
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions
```

Or

It should be

```py
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
```

both works fine

Comment: FirefoxOptions will not work instead FirefoxOptions() will work.
Try it

Comment: see, either use Options() or FirefoxOptions()

Comment: You yourself is using `options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()`, check you code

Comment: yup, so I am saying both the solution will work. 

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below code with firefox options :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver_path = "D:\geckodriver.exe"
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options, executable_path= driver_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://amazon.de')
print(driver.title)
```

**Output :**

> Amazon.de: Günstige Preise für Elektronik & Foto, Filme, Musik,
> Bücher, Games, Spielzeug & mehr